# Selenium WebDriver, 2 окна с одним и тем же handler

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Есть веб приложение с кнопкой, после нажатия на кнопку откывается 2 окно и нужно переключится на него. Проблема в том, что если я беру getWindowHandle() второго окна, то он такойже как и у первого

```
String originalWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();
    final Set<String> oldWindowsSet = driver.getWindowHandles();

    util.elementVisible(By.id("ucBillingRepList_lvReportList_ctrl0_hlRep")).click();

    String newWindow = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
            .until(new ExpectedCondition<String>() {
                       public String apply(WebDriver driver) {
                           Set<String> newWindowsSet = driver.getWindowHandles();
                           newWindowsSet.removeAll(oldWindowsSet);
                           return newWindowsSet.size() > 0 ?
                                   newWindowsSet.iterator().next() : null;
                       }
                   }
            );

    driver.switchTo().window(newWindow);
    driver.close();

    driver.switchTo().window(originalWindow);
```

и вот что пишет:

```
Started InternetExplorerDriver server (32-bit)
```

> 3.4.0.0 Listening on port 22062 Only local connections are allowed Jul 12, 2017 10:55:24 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake
>   createSession INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
>   org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: Unable to get browser
>   (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
>   Command duration or timeout: 31 milliseconds Build info: version:
>   '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown' System info: host:
>   'KHO-0493-WS', ip: '10.4.69.161', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch:
>   'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_131' Driver info:
>   org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver Capabilities
>   [{se:ieOptions={browserAttachTimeout=0.0,
>   ie.enableFullPageScreenshot=true, enablePersistentHover=true,
>   ie.forceCreateProcessApi=false, ie.forceShellWindowsApi=false,
>   ignoreZoomSetting=true, ie.fileUploadDialogTimeout=3000.0,
>   ie.useLegacyFileUploadDialogHandling=false, nativeEvents=true,
>   ie.ensureCleanSession=true, elementScrollBehavior=0.0,
>   ie.browserCommandLineSwitches=, requireWindowFocus=false,
>   initialBrowserUrl=https://cnbilllm.fuib.com/main.aspx,
>   ignoreProtectedModeSettings=true, enableElementCacheCleanup=true},
>   browserName=internet explorer, pageLoadStrategy=normal,
>   javascriptEnabled=true, version=11, platform=WINDOWS,
>   unexpectedAlertBehaviour=dismiss}] Session ID:
>   a73aef0e-cbd2-4f0a-a46b-67237e3a12ad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался, если у кого то будет такая же проблема с IE, просто уберите капабилити 
caps.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true);